# PS3 Loading without sound

Tags: ps3

Okay, so I have the old fat PS3 80gb, which I upgraded with a 250gb hdd ages ago. For the last while, not sure, some stuff has been loading without sound.

1. I get a loading chime and XMB tones
2. I can play music from the XMB without problem, nice sound
3. I can watch TV through the 4OD, iPlayers and the like no issues
4. Game trailers work fine, but, they only work if I press `triangle` and select the 'Play from beginning'. If I then exit the playback using `circle` and then play it again, I get no sound
5. I rented a movie from PSN yesterday and it took me 8 tries of playing and quitting to get the sound to work
6. I can't get Little Big Planet to work with sound at all this morning

If anyone has any ideas please do chip in, this is starting to really frustrate me. Infamous seems to load with sound every time, Kill Team is a 3/10 chance of getting sound. So it seems to be some games more than others.

I've reset my Sound Settings again, but short of a system factory reset, I'm really not sure what to do at this point.

---

Taking a note from the 'Play from beginning' I tried pressing `triangle` and then 'Start' from the games menu and this doesn't seem to work either.

---

Created a thread on the tech help sony forums also, http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/Technical-Help/Games-movies-and-videos-loading-without-sound/td-p/13842737

Comment: I assume you've checked the physical connections on the device?

Comment: Yep, otherwise the music and XMB noise wouldn't work! ;)

Comment: Is the PS3 running loud and/or hot? Perhaps it's on its way out...

Comment: I will check that, I hadn't thought of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you connected through HDMI for audio? Have you tried hooking it up with another type of connection such as a analog sound cable? Some TVs have shoddy HDMI Audio implementations and switching video modes can cause their audio to "desync" from the stream. You could also try changing which types of streams are sent to the TV could help as well, reducing it to only PCM perhaps instead of Dolby may help it when it transitions from program to program.

You can try shutting the TV off and turning it back on when it happens as well, and that may nudge the HDMI connection into working.

Comment: I've not tried yet, but I think this is worth accepting as it makes sense and will help other people searching for this issue.